# Update the common values in the last repeated obj of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I've an array in which some objects have some common properties like `name`, `surname` or both `name` and `surname` with `dob` and some different properties like `id`,`type`. I want to return a new array where the common properties remain same but `id` and `type` get updated in an array of all the values with common properties in all the objects which are common or just in the last obj which is common.

Array

```
const arr = [
    {
        name: 'Rohan',
        dob: '1-1-2000',
        type: "A",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'Rohan',
        dob: '1-1-2000',
        type: "B",
        id: 2
    },
    {
        surName: 'Mehra',
        dob: '2-2-2000',
        type: "A",
        id: 3
    },
    {
        surName: 'Mehra',
        dob: '2-2-2000',
        type: "B",
        id: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'Same',
        dob: '4-4-2001',
        type: "E",
        id: 5
    },
    {
        name: 'Akshay',
        surName: 'Roy',
        dob: '3-3-2000',
        type: "C",
        id: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'Akshay',
        surName: 'Roy',
        dob: '3-3-2000',
        type: "D",
        id: 7
    },
]
```

I want to get the following result (or updated values in an array in all the properties which had different values) -

```
const result = [
    {
        name: 'Rohan',
        dob: '1-1-2000',
        type: "A",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'Rohan',
        dob: '1-1-2000',
        type: ["A","B"],
        id: [1,2]
    },
    {
        surName: 'Mehra',
        dob: '2-2-2000',
        type: "A",
        id: 3
    },
    {
        surName: 'Mehra',
        dob: '2-2-2000',
        type: ["A","B"],
        id: [3,4]
    },
    {
        name: 'Same',
        dob: '4-4-2001',
        type: "E",
        id: 5
    },
    {
        name: 'Akshay',
        surName: 'Roy',
        dob: '3-3-2000',
        type: "C",
        id: 6
    },
    {
        name: 'Akshay',
        surName: 'Roy',
        dob: '3-3-2000',
        type: ["C","D"],
        id: [6,7]
    },
]
```

I am trying with map but not able to proceed further with the approach for the solution -

```
const result = [];
const final = arr.map((item,index) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(arr);
    const common = keys.map((innerItem) => {
        if(innerItem === ) {

        }
    })
})
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a 'group by and sum' situation, which can be addressed with a [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) call. In this case, since you are wanting to group by multiple properties, we can generate a composite key from those properties to use in the accumulator object

```
const compositeKey = `${o.name ?? ''}_${o.surName ?? ''}_${o.dob ?? ''}`;
```

here using the [nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to accommodate possible missing properties.

This solution will return a new array with duplicates grouped into single entries.

```js
const arr = [{ name: 'Rohan', dob: '1-1-2000', type: "A", id: 1 }, { name: 'Rohan', dob: '1-1-2000', type: "B", id: 2 }, { surName: 'Mehra', dob: '2-2-2000', type: "A", id: 3 }, { surName: 'Mehra', dob: '2-2-2000', type: "B", id: 4 }, { name: 'Same', dob: '4-4-2001', type: "E", id: 5 }, { name: 'Akshay', surName: 'Roy', dob: '3-3-2000', type: "C", id: 6 }, { name: 'Akshay', surName: 'Roy', dob: '3-3-2000', type: "D", id: 7 },];

const result = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((a, { type, id, ...o }) => {
    const compositeKey = `${o.name ?? ''}_${o.surName ?? ''}_${o.dob ?? ''}`;

    a[compositeKey] ??= { ...o, type: [], id: [] };
    
    a[compositeKey].type.push(type);
    a[compositeKey].id.push(id);

    return a;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If, however, you want to return an array that is the same length as the original with updated `type` and `id` properties listing all occurrences you can instead use a `map()` call and pass an object to track duplicates.

```js
const arr = [{ name: 'Rohan', dob: '1-1-2000', type: "A", id: 1 }, { name: 'Rohan', dob: '1-1-2000', type: "B", id: 2 }, { surName: 'Mehra', dob: '2-2-2000', type: "A", id: 3 }, { surName: 'Mehra', dob: '2-2-2000', type: "B", id: 4 }, { name: 'Same', dob: '4-4-2001', type: "E", id: 5 }, { name: 'Akshay', surName: 'Roy', dob: '3-3-2000', type: "C", id: 6 }, { name: 'Akshay', surName: 'Roy', dob: '3-3-2000', type: "D", id: 7 },];

const
  dupes = {},
  result = arr.map(({ type, id, ...o }) => {
    const compositeKey = `${o.name ?? ''}_${o.surName ?? ''}_${o.dob ?? ''}`;

    const { typeArr, idArr } = (dupes[compositeKey] ??= { typeArr: [], idArr: [] });

    typeArr.push(type);
    idArr.push(id);

    return { ...o, type: typeArr, id: idArr };
  });

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

**Edit**

Here are two generalized snippets in answer to your comment regarding accommodating objects with unknown properties.

The first accumulates into an array instead of an object, and declares a `findDuplicates()` function to locate elements in the accumulator for which [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) property other than `type` and `id` match. If not found, a new object is pushed into the accumulator.

```js
const
  arr = [
    { dob: '1-1-2000', country: 'Mexico', name: "Rohan", type: "F", id: 8 },
    { country: 'Mexico', dob: '1-1-2000', type: "A", id: 1 },
    { dob: '1-1-2000', country: 'Mexico', type: "B", id: 2 },
    { dob: '2-2-2000', type: "A", id: 3, surName: 'Mehra', },
    { surName: 'Mehra', dob: '2-2-2000', type: "B", id: 4 },
    { name: 'Same', dob: '4-4-2001', type: "E", id: 5 },
    { city: 'Paris', hobby: 'foo', dob: '3-3-2000', type: "C", id: 6 },
    { city: 'Paris', hobby: 'foo', dob: '3-3-2000', type: "D", id: 7 }
  ],

  findDuplicateIndex = (obj, arr) => arr.findIndex(({ type, id, ...element }) => (
    Object.keys(obj).length === Object.keys(element).length
    && Object.keys(obj).every(key => obj[key] === element[key]))),

  result = arr.reduce((a, { type, id, ...o }) => {
    let duplicateIndex = findDuplicateIndex(o, a);

    if (duplicateIndex === -1) {
      a.push({ ...o, type: [], id: [] });
      duplicateIndex = a.length - 1;
    }

    a[duplicateIndex].type.push(type);
    a[duplicateIndex].id.push(id);

    return a;
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The second uses the same compositeKey method as the original answer, but reduces all the properties of the object other than `type` and `id` into the composite key rather than accessing specific properties. Keys are first sorted to ensure ordering of the resulting compositeKey, and only values of type 'string' and 'number' are included.

```js
const arr = [
  { country: 'Mexico', dob: '1-1-2000', type: "A", id: 1 },
  { dob: '1-1-2000', country: 'Mexico', type: "B", id: 2 },
  { dob: '2-2-2000', type: "A", id: 3, surName: 'Mehra', },
  { surName: 'Mehra', dob: '2-2-2000', type: "B", id: 4 },
  { name: 'Same', dob: '4-4-2001', type: "E", id: 5 },
  { city: 'Paris', hobby: 'foo', dob: '3-3-2000', type: "C", id: 6 },
  { city: 'Paris', hobby: 'foo', dob: '3-3-2000', type: "D", id: 7 }
];

const result = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((a, { type, id, ...o }) => {

    // define compositeKey by reducing all properties except type and id
    let compositeKey = Object.keys(o)
      .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))  // sort keys to ensure ordering in compositeKey
      .reduce((acc, key) => {  // only add to key if value is of type 'string' or 'number'
        if (typeof o[key] === 'string' || typeof o[key] === 'number') {
          acc += `${key}:${o[key]}_`
        }
        return acc;
      }, '');

    a[compositeKey] ??= { ...o, type: [], id: [] };

    a[compositeKey].type.push(type);
    a[compositeKey].id.push(id);

    return a;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi @pilchard , thank you, the answer looks great, the `name`,`surname` key names may change depending on the response it can be anything like `city`, `hobby`, etc.. Is there any way we can achieve it, if we don't what the keys name will be only `dob`, `type` and `id is known.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample with how you can do it. It is not the most elegant solution, but I think it is easy enough to understand.

```js
const arr = [{ name: 'Rohan', dob: '1-1-2000', type: "A", id: 1 }, { name: 'Rohan', dob: '1-1-2000', type: "B", id: 2 }, { surName: 'Mehra', dob: '2-2-2000', type: "A", id: 3 }, { surName: 'Mehra', dob: '2-2-2000', type: "B", id: 4 }, { name: 'Same', dob: '4-4-2001', type: "E", id: 5 }, { name: 'Akshay', surName: 'Roy', dob: '3-3-2000', type: "C", id: 6 }, { name: 'Akshay', surName: 'Roy', dob: '3-3-2000', type: "D", id: 7 },];

arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(item);
  // compare the current item with each of the remaning items
  for (let i = index + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let foundCommon = false;
    keys.forEach((innerItemKey) => {
      if (foundCommon) return; // avoid adding more properties
      // avoid checking certain keys
      if (innerItemKey === 'id' || innerItemKey === 'type') return;
      // check if the next item shares any values among keys and modify it
      if (item[innerItemKey] === arr[i][innerItemKey]) {
        foundCommon = true;
        arr[i]['id'] = [item['id'], arr[i]['id']];
        arr[i]['type'] = [item['type'], arr[i]['type']];
      }
    });
  }
});

console.log('result by modifying existing array:', arr);
```